# Kepp biggest values for each column of the pandas.DataFrame respecting indexes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sorting

my expectation that

```
cheer_leading.nlargest(10, s_cols, keep='all')
```

will return top performers for each column, but in reality, it returns only performers in the first columns. So to get the largest in every category I have to iterate through columns and save indexes manually.

```
top_ = set()
for c in s_cols:
    top_ |= set(cheer_leading[c].nlargest(10).index)
    
cheer_leading.loc[top_]
```

is there an easier way to achieve the same?

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
out = df.apply(lambda x : x.nlargest(2).index)
```

Comment: this does not keep the values, but replaces the table with indexes. But awesome output, still